# App runs fine in iOS Simulator, crashes on device

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

My monotouch iPhone/iPod app (named Assement) runs fine in the iOS simulator, no warnings and no errors anywhere.  However when I deploy it to a device, it crashes immediately on startup.

I took a look a the crash dump (complete .crash file can be [downloaded here](http://www.mmtsweng.com/x2/Assessment_Ipod_Crash.zip)), but it doesn't even look like it gets out of Application.Main():

```
14  Assessment                      0x002a0ffc mono_handle_exception (mini-exceptions.c:1831)
15  Assessment                      0x002c64cc mono_arm_throw_exception (exceptions-arm.c:158)
16  Assessment                      0x00197cc4 throw_exception + 4018  CoreFoundation                   0x000a4daa __handleUncaughtException + 206
  -->  17  Assessment                       0x003fda68 monotouch_exception_handler (monotouch-glue.m:834)
  -->  18  CoreFoundation                   0x000a4daa __handleUncaughtException + 206
19  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000088cc _objc_terminate + 148
20  libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00063100 __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) + 76
21  libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00063178 std::terminate() + 16
22  libstdc++.6.dylib               0x000632a0 __cxa_throw + 100
23  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00006f28 objc_exception_throw + 104
24  CoreFoundation                  0x000a4abc +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 64
25  CoreFoundation                  0x000a4af0 +[NSException raise:format:] + 24
26  UIKit                           0x00290af8 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1724
27  UIKit                           0x00292638 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 132
28  UIKit                           0x00051b10 -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFile] + 136
29  UIKit                           0x0004b9e4 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 248
30  UIKit                           0x000052dc -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1468
31  UIKit                           0x00004b14 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 60
32  UIKit                           0x000043ac _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6816
33  GraphicsServices                0x00005c80 PurpleEventCallback + 1040
34  CoreFoundation                  0x000365c4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 22
35  CoreFoundation                  0x00036582 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 158
36  CoreFoundation                  0x0002882e __CFRunLoopRun + 574
37  CoreFoundation                  0x00028504 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 220
38  CoreFoundation                  0x00028412 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 54
 --> 39  UIKit                          0x0004a54c -[UIApplication _run] + 540
 --> 40  UIKit                          0x00047550 UIApplicationMain + 964
 --> 41  Assessment                     0x00024bcc wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 232
 --> 42  Assessment                     0x001e9420 X2_AssessmentApp_Application_Main_string__ + 144
43  Assessment                      0x001673f8 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 192
```

Application.Main is the standard one that is generated when the project is created (Neither code below works, the namespace-qualified commented version has the same result):

```
namespace XXXXXX.App //anonymized
{
public class Application
{
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        //UIApplication.Main(args, null, "XXXXXX.App.AppDelegate");
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
    }
}
// The name AppDelegate is referenced in the MainWindow.xib file.
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
   // This method is invoked when the application has loaded its UI and its ready to run
    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Finished Launching"); ...
```

Am I correct in assuming that it is failing when loading the main nib? That would just be simply MainWindow.xib, again out-of-the-box, as the first thing I do in the UIApplicationDelegate.FinishedLaunching() method is load my own viewcontroller and view... I would almost expect that there could be an error in that code, but it's not even getting that far.

Environment:

- MonoTouch Professional 3.2.6
- MonoDevelop 2.4.2 release 20402004
- iPod Touch 2nd Gen (4.2.1)

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You're getting a crash on startup when ObjC is throwing an exception, what does the iPhone Console say?

Comment: Nothing on the console... unless I'm not hooked up to it correctly? I'll look into that.

Comment: I can't post my own answer for 24 hours... but Geoff, you led me to the solution.

My MainWindow.xib file's build action had been set to CONTENT instead of Page. User error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goeff lead me to the correct answer.

I had somehow changed the MainWindow.xib build action from Page to Content.... Completely user error.

The Console log for the device clearly stated the problem (unlike the crash dump):

```
<Notice>: Unhandled Exception: MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/11DD588C-E16C-499D-AE0C-E56F59D90391/Assessment.app> (loaded)' with name 'MainWindow'
```